# Boot to text mode by default on LiveUSB?

Tags: boot, live-usb

Recently, i try to remaster my lucyd with UCK. Everything is OK! Just wondering, by pressing *esc* i can see all the process. So, is there any way to make it happen by default, to boot TEXT MODE on live usb. Thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0):

If by 'booting Text mode' you are referring to verbosely displaying the boot-up process, without having to press the Escape key every time, here's how you would do that.

In a Terminal, run these commands:

```
sudo sed -i 's/"quiet splash"/""/g' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: thanks for quick respond :)  will try it, emm.. So, i should type that command on chroot environment, right ?

Comment: Just open up the **Terminal** application and copy/paste those two commands in there, one by one. Press Enter after each line. When prompted for your password, enter your user's password. It is normal that your password is not displayed while you are typing it. Just type it, and press Enter after.

Comment: on liveusb running, typing #1 command. Then got error message when type *update-grub*  please T_T

Comment: Well give me the error message.. I can't guess :)